# AS3: removeChild

Tags: actionscript-3, oop

So i finally got my menu working, but i want to remove the current clip when you go back to the menu. I thought this would work, unfortunately it doesn't. Any ideas on how to get it working? I use OOP by the way, this is one of my classes.

```
import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;

public class MainClip extends MovieClip {

    var currentClip:MovieClip;

    public static const MY_FINISHED_MAINGAME_EVENT:String = "my_finished_mainGame_event"

    //constructor code
    public function MainClip() {
        backToMenu.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, openMainMenu);
    }

    function removeCurrent () {
        currentClip = new MainClip;
        removeChild(currentClip);
    }

    //terug naar het Menu
    public function openMainMenu (event:MouseEvent):void
    {
        dispatchEvent(new Event(MY_FINISHED_MAINGAME_EVENT));
        currentClip = new IntroClip();
        addChild(currentClip);
        currentClip.x=200;
        currentClip.y=200;
    }
}
```

Comment: Is this your main class (document class)? If so, document class is initialized and added to the display list automatically, you don't need to create a new instance of it using the *new* keyword. Even if you did create a new instance of it, you are trying to remove it with removeChild but it has never been added to the display list, so it will throw an error.

Comment: It's the same issue as in your previous post. You should only dispatch the event, and in your main class (Kikkers), listen for the event remove the current clip and readd it. The only place where you need a reference to the currentClip is in the main class.